# Add the array to the css 'content' in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to display the data on the css style content. I have this code:

```
if (ext){
    switch (ext.toLowerCase())
    {
        case 'doc': pos = 'doc'; break;
        case 'bmp': pos = 'bmp'; break;                       
        case 'jpg': pos = 'jpg'; break;
        case 'jpeg': pos = 'jpeg'; break;
        case 'mp3': pos = 'mp3'; break;
        case 'avi': pos = 'avi'; break;
        case 'wmv': pos = 'wmv'; break;
        case 'flv': pos = 'flv'; break;
        case 'pdf': pos = 'pdf'; break;
        case 'txt': pos = 'txt'; break;
        case 'xls': pos = 'xls'; break;
        case 'rar': pos = 'rar'; break;
        case 'zip': pos = 'zip'; break;
        default: pos = 'doc'; break;
    };
    fileIcon:after.css({content:'pos'})
};
```

});

How can i show this `case data` write to css:

```
.fileIcon:after
{ content: "";
}
```

**The decision**: https://jsfiddle.net/e9wjzqjd/3/ if need someone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could append a new `<style>` tag to the `<head>`

```
var cssRule ='.fileIcon:after{ content:"' + pos + '";}';
$('<style>').text(cssRule).appendTo('head');
```

You can't directly access pseudo classes like `:after` in the dom using script

Comment: Sorry, can you show how it should be in my example? https://jsfiddle.net/e9wjzqjd/

Comment: need to add additional class (or id) for each see https://jsfiddle.net/e9wjzqjd/1/  Inspect the link, can see the rule applied

Comment: should really try @epascarello approach. Should work without needing to add additional class for each one

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to use a data attribute and not write a CSS rule

```js
document.getElementById("x").setAttribute("data-type", "pos");
```

```css
div[data-type]:after { 
 content: attr(data-type); 
}
```

```html
<div id="x" data-type=""></div>
```